# BizTalk WCF-WebHttp Adapter SQL Exception

Tags: wcf, biztalk

I have created a WCF-Webhttp adapter in BizTalk Server 2020 and a receive location. When trying to make a request towards the endpoint I get the following error. Looks like BizTalk WCF adapter is not able to authenticate to the SQL server instance. Any clues where this connection can be configured?

> WebHost failed to process a request.
>   Sender Information: System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment+HostingManager/2011106
>       Exception: System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException: The service '/BizTalkWcfService123456/Service1.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.. ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user 'QUBIZ\LPT16$'.
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, SqlAuthenticationProviderManager sqlAuthProviderManager)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>      at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>      at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
>      at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
>      at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
>      at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
>      at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
>      at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
>      at Microsoft.BizTalk.CommonSettings.CBizTalkSettings.LoadSettings(String receiveLocationUrl)
>      at Microsoft.BizTalk.CommonSettings.CBizTalkSettings..ctor(String receiveLocationUrl)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
>      at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>      at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
>      at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
>      at System.Activator.CreateInstance(String assemblyString, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, Evidence securityInfo, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
>      at System.Activator.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
>      at System.AppDomain.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
>      at System.AppDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(String assemblyName, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
>      at System.AppDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(String assemblyName, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
>      at Microsoft.BizTalk.CommonSettings.CBizTalkSettingsLookup.CreateInstanceInDefaultDomain(String typeName, Object[] args)
>      at Microsoft.BizTalk.TransportProxy.Interop.IBTTransportProxy.RegisterIsolatedReceiver(String url, IBTTransportConfig callback)
>      at Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Runtime.WcfIsolatedReceiver`2.RegisterIsolatedReceiver(Uri uri)
>      at Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Runtime.WebServiceHostFactory`3.CreateServiceHost(String constructorString, Uri[] baseAddresses)
>      at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.CreateService(String normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)
>      at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.ActivateService(ServiceActivationInfo serviceActivationInfo, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)
>      at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)
>      at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.EnsureServiceAvailableFast(String relativeVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)
>    Process Name: w3wp
>    Process ID: 20216

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though the account running the host instance doesn't have the appropriate database permissions to read the adapter configuration.

First of all, make sure that the account is added to the BizTalk Application Users (if a BizTalk host) or the BizTalk Isolated Host Users (if an isolated host) group. This should grant all necessary permissions; unless the group or the BizTalk Management or MessageBox Databases have been tampered with.

[This documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/windows-groups-and-user-accounts-in-biztalk-server) describes the built-in Windows groups expected by default by BizTalk Server. It is possible to customise the groups expected by BizTalk away from the defaults, so you can run the [BizTalk Configuration Wizard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/install-and-config-guides/configure-biztalk-server#custom-configuration) and choose Custom Configuration to check what has been configured.

Comment: Yes indeed, as it turns out I used an Application Pool user that did not have access to either SQL or Biztalk.Thanks!